# Cannot connect to Samba share from Windows 11, have tried EVERYTHING

Tags: networking, server, samba

I have an old PC that I use as a server. It mostly is used for serving up Plex and family photos/videos - just three SATA drives attached for storage.  The machine runs Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 installed on SATA A ... personal files on SATA B and C.  It is not connected to a display, so I use PuTTy to manage it from my Windows 11 PCs.

Everything was working on it perfectly for a year or more, when last week I lost the ability to mount SATA A or B using the "Map Network Drive" features from my Win11 machines.  I started poking around, tried to use online forums and reddit posts to self diagnose, but I'm stuck.  Here's what I know.

The `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file seems to be setup correctly.  `testparm` dumps this

```
user@optiserver990:~$ testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
        auto services = global
        bind interfaces only = Yes
        client max protocol = SMB3
        interfaces = lo eno1
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        logging = file
        map to guest = Bad User
        max log size = 1000
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        server role = standalone server
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        unix password sync = Yes
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
        browseable = No
        comment = All Printers
        create mask = 0700
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = Yes


[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[TERADRIVE]
        path = /media/TERADRIVE
        read only = No


[DECATERA]
        path = /media/DECATERA
        read only = No


[HOME]
        comment = user's home directory on Optiserver990
        path = /home/user
        read only = No
```

I cannot connect to any of the defined 'TERADRIVE' 'DECATERA' or 'HOME' shares.  When I am connected via SSH, I can use `smbclient` to list shares and I get this.

```
user@optiserver990:~$ smbclient -L 10.0.0.5
Password for [WORKGROUP\user]:

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
        TERADRIVE       Disk
        DECATERA        Disk
        HOME            Disk      user's home directory on Optiserver990
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (optiserver990 server (Samba, Ubuntu))
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available
```

I noticed the line SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available, so I poked around and saw various people online say to enable SMB1 protocol on the Windows client side via "Enable Optional Features" ... that did not fix my problem.  Other people said to add lines to `/etc/samba/smb.conf` setting various max and min SMB protocol versions. That also did not fix my problem.

One thing I *can* do is I seem to be able to use `smbclient` to connect to the share.  Now, that is all via PuTTy'ing into the server, so maybe it's just that I'm connecting the server to itself?

Anyhow, this is what I get and I thought it at least verified that Samba is up and configured properly.

```
user@optiserver990:~$ smbclient \\\\10.0.0.5\\DECATERA -m SMB3
Password for [WORKGROUP\user]:
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \> dir
  .                                   D        0  Sun Jul  2 10:08:41 2023
  ..                                  D        0  Mon Oct 17 14:16:51 2022
  SABnzbd complete                    D        0  Fri Dec 15 19:54:02 2023
  Movies                              D        0  Fri Nov 17 21:46:43 2023
  TV-Shows                            D        0  Fri Oct  6 21:00:00 2023
  HelloWorld.txt                      A      242  Wed May 17 22:52:05 2023
  lost+found                          D        0  Mon Oct 17 14:24:57 2022
  SABnzbd incomplete                  D        0  Fri Dec 15 19:54:02 2023

                7751273184 blocks of size 1024. 4576001592 blocks available
```

It also works if I leave off the `-m SMB3` option, or if I pass `-m SMB2`.  I tried `-m SMB1` and it said:

> WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'SMB1' for parameter 'client max protocol'.

When I'm connected this way, it does show up as an active connection inside of Webmin's Samba panel.

[image]

Confusingly, if I pass `smbstatus --shares` I get a bunch of nothing.

```
user@optiserver990:~$ sudo smbstatus --shares
[sudo] password for user:

Service      pid     Machine       Connected at                     Encryption   Signing
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Lastly, I tried to connect from an Ubuntu client, just to isolate the issue.  It also did not work.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ smbclient -U user //10.0.0.5/TERADRIVE
Password for [WORKGROUP\user]:
do_connect: Connection to 10.0.0.5 failed (Error NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT)
```

Everything else is working well - I can use other machines to connect to programs like Webmin, Sabnzbd, etc.  Plex is playing movies. SSH is working.

I just *don’t* have GUI access to mounted shares from the Windows client side.  I am banging my head against a wall!  Please help

Answer (score 0):

I have found myself in the same situation and finally, I could solve it. Basically, I had to force SMB3 protocol in the Samba server:

`protocol = SMB3`

Source:
https://snippets.pichler.network/docs/linux/#sharing-a-folder-with-the-windows-network-protocol